# remove duplicate for only title laravel

Tags: laravel, view, duplicates, title

In laravel 5.7 in my web controller

```
public function index(Request $request){

    $plan = Plan::All();

    return view('web.plan.index', compact('plan'));
}
```

In my view file

```
                   @foreach($plan as $singlePlan)
                   
                  @if(Carbon\Carbon::parse($singlePlan->date)->format('m')==10)
                        
                        <div class="row brow bg-gray ">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="row-title">
                                    <strong>12.31</strong>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                         
            
                    
                    <div class="m-departures">
                        <div class="row brow last-row" >
                            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col hidden-xs">
                                <div class="td center">Dec 21-22</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col">
                                <div class="td"><a href="#" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">Fest</a></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-6 col visible-xs">
                                <div class="td">2 day</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-2 col hidden-xs">
                                <div class="td">2 day</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-6 col">
                                <div class="td">
                                    <span class="orange schedule-status">
                                         4                                        
                                    </span>          
                                                                  
                                </div>                                   
                            </div>                               
                            <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-12 col tour-link hidden-sm hidden-xs">
                                <div class="td center"><a href="#" >view</a></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                 
                        
                @endif
                      @endforeach
```

and my web looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idLzO.jpg)

but I want it to look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4KqX.jpg)

How can I remove the duplicate title?

Comment: move the row with 12.31 out of your for loop

Comment: there are many other months condition. if i remove this, all of my month condition will be removed...

Comment: then you will need a variable $current that stores [month, year] and compare that every time in a loop if the value is different you print out the month.year heading and update $current to the new value.

Comment: please show me the code to do that, i am new to laravel sorry

Answer (score 2):

It would be better to group your data by the month before passing data to blade template. By using collection method mapToGroups
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-maptogroups

```
$planGroups = Plan::get()->mapToGroups(function($plan, $key) {
    $planDate = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($plan->date);

    return ["{$planDate->month} {$planDate->year}" => $plan];
})
->all();
```

You will get several groups of plans grouped by month, e.g.

```
[
    '11 2020' => [plan, plan, ...],
    '12 2020' => [plan, plan, plan, ...]
]
```

Then in your blade template you can loop through the months then loop through the plans.

```
@foreach ($planGroups as $month => $plans)
    // show month heading

    @foreach ($plans as $plan)
        // show each plan
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: it works,  in // show each plan, i can show plan by {{$plan->title}}, in    // show month heading {{$plans->date}} not working pls help

Comment: Try $plans->first()->date